# Integrating Caching with Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to integrate lvl 1 caching with my spring boot app. I am trying to cache the user using the id as the key.  However when trying to retrieve information using their phone to retrieve user data, the error is the following "Adding cacheable method 'findByPhoneNumber' with attribute".

UserRepository:

```
    @Cacheable(value = "userEntity", key = "#result.id", unless = "#result != null")
    Optional<UserEntity> findByEmail(String email);

    @Cacheable(value = "userEntity", key = "#result.id", unless = "#result != null")
    Optional<UserEntity> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
```

UserEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="user_name", unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="email", unique = true)
    private String email;
```

Error Message:

```
2020-05-15 00:54:27 - Adding cacheable method 'findByPhoneNumber' with attribute: [Builder[public final java.util.Optional com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.findByPhoneNumber(java.lang.String)] caches=[userEntity] | key='#result.id' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='#result != null' | sync='false']
2020-05-15 00:54:27 - Adding cacheable method 'findByPhoneNumber' with attribute: [Builder[public abstract java.util.Optional com.howtodoinjava.demo.repository.UserRepository.findByPhoneNumber(java.lang.String)] caches=[userEntity] | key='#result.id' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='#result != null' | sync='false']
2020-05-15 00:54:27 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:265)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.key(CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.java:104)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:778)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:575)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:518)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:401)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.findByPhoneNumber(Unknown Source)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.service.CIAMPhoneService.doesUserExist(CIAMPhoneService.java:37)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller.CIAMPhoneController.registerUser(CIAMPhoneController.java:49)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: I think misunderstood how it @Cacheable works, if you wanna cache a method that takes in a String, the key should be dependent on that String, thus ' key = "phoneNumber" ' would make more sense. So for your case, i think the "key" and "unless" are causing the errors. try removing them and see if it works. This is a great resource to help you understand it more https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Good point regarding the key should always be a string.  I would prefer if the key is the id.  This will help me have one key instead of two (one for email and one for phone number).  The problem is I do not know the key until the  method returns a UserEntity.

Comment: That's not what I mean. If you're adding caching to a method that findsPhonesByNumber, the key should be the number. However if you're caching a method that just finds a user, would be obvious to use id as key. it depends on the method you're adding caching to.